# wordpress post category shows double`

Tags: theme-development

my question is i wanted to created a filter for example portfolio filter with mix it up java script plugin

i have one problem  i wanted to show only one post even if it has been assigned multiple category but get the both category slug and echo it once is it possible to do

for example let suppose i have a post name hello world i have assigned it two category food and sport i wanted echo the post once but get the both category slug in wp_query loop